# Sharepoint Workspace creates _cts folder

Tags: workspace

With Sharepoint 2010 in use at my company's intranet, I started using Sharepoint Workspace, since it gives me faster and easier access to files and functions like check out/in etc.

However, several ov my colleges have started complaining that as soon as I connect a new project to my Workspace, it creates a _cts folder on the Documents root, which then shows up for them when using e.g. the web interface. Is this necessary? Can I stop it?

It is definitely possible to remove the folder after I have connected the project, but this is both tedious and dangerous. Tedious because it has to be done for every person who connects to a project, and for every project. Dangerous because I assume it may be used by other people in some projects, in which case I really shouldn't delete it.

I've noticed it is possible to filter out the _cts folder from the file view, by altering the Default view for the library. This partly solves the problem, but it still shows up in the Folders pane in Sharepoint Workspace for that project. Is there a way to filter the Folders pane as well?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem. I never used sharepoint workspace though

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid not. However, I'm pretty sure my issue was linked to Sharepoint Workspace, what was your use case?

Comment: After we deployed our solution package, then the cts folder started appearing in all document libraries. THere is no code that involves changing that